# Reading multiple json objects stored in a single file

Tags: json

I have stored multiple json objects in a single file **file.txt**

```
{"article": "....", "title": "...."}{"article": "....", "title": "...."}
```

I used the following code for *dumping* json objects

```
import json 

data = {}
data['title'] = '....'
data['article'] = '....'

data_2 = {}
data_2['title'] = '.....'
data_2['article'] = '.....'

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data , file, ensure_ascii=False)
    json.dump(data , file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I have done this on a larger scale using a for loop

I tried reading these objects but I got the the following error

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 10329 - line 1 column 295676 (char 10328 - 295675)
```

then I stored each object on a different line

```
{"article": "....", "title": "...."}
{"article": "....", "title": "...."}
```

which led to another error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I have around 4k objects stored in this way therefore storing them in seperate dictionaries is also not feasible

(An approach suggested on a similar question)

Any input on this would be appreciated

Comment: I think you just need to store them as an array in the single file. Just put [ at the beginning, ] at the end, and commas between the object (which you could do with search and replace if you've lost the source data). When you parse it into your file, it will be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON file should contain just one JSON for it to work. In your case you could wrap all those dicts in a single list and output that as a single JSON:

```
import json 

lst = []

data = {}
data['title'] = '....'
data['article'] = '....'
lst.append(data)

data_2 = {}
data_2['title'] = '.....'
data_2['article'] = '.....'
lst.append(data_2)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(lst, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

When reading from that JSON file, you will get the list containing all the dicts you had put into it.